How to show a data-toggle class with ajax and php
I have difficulties with the legagy code. I need to implement the function that opens de data-toggle, I have include parsedResponse in the verify data, since is the responsible to show the response of info.  But it's not working.. sobody help?
function checkInfo(input_data) {
    var requestData = {
        data: input_data
    };
    var info = input_data;
    $.ajax({
        url: "/endpoint/search",
        type: 'POST',
        data: requestData,
        success: function(response) {
            $('.search_result').html(response);
            process_contacts();
            process_opportunities();
            verify_data(info, function(parsedResponse){
                if ($('#collapseOne').hasClass('collapse') && !($('#collapseOne').hasClass('show')) && parsedResponse.success === true){
                    $('.open_contact').click();
                    console.log(parsedResponse.success);
                }
            });
        }
    });
}

function verify_data(data) {
    $.ajax({
            url: '/endpoint/verify',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                data: data
            }
        })
        .done(function(response) {
            var parsedResponse = $.parseJSON(response);
            if (parsedResponse) {
                $('.save_info').removeAttr('disabled');
            } else {
                $('.save_info').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            }
            return parsedResponse;
        })
}


I expect to be able to reach the parsedResponse as true and do the click event.

You are passing a callback function as second parameter in your verify_data call - but the function doesn't do anything with that parameter. You need to either make your function accept that second parameter, and then actually call the callback function; or you do let parsedResponse = verify_data(info);, and then use that value afterwards.

Yes, it was missing the paramenter.  Thank you.
